# How to reverse the contents of an Xml file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an xml file and what I want to do is reverse its elements. I mean the first element should be last and last should be first. I want all the elements to reverse.

Ex. This should be

```
<Elements>
<Element1>
<Element2>
<Element3>
<Element4>
</ Elements>
```

This

```
<Elements>
<Element4>
<Element3>
<Element2>
<Element1>
</ Elements>
```

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have written to do this?

Comment: This question does not make sense. The XML standard makes no representation about the order in which an XML parser should read the elements. While all parsers I know read the elements in the order they are found, there actually *is* no order of elements on the same hierarchical level. So there's actually nothing to "reverse".

Answer (score 3):

Push them on a stack an then pop them off to rebuild it in reverse order. Do this recursively for every set of nested elements in the document.

Comment: @maestrosan11 Would you mind trying something? You've gotten a couple answers which should get you off in the right direction. Nobody here is terribly motivated to just do it for you.

Comment: @ShaneWealti Thanks for the advice. I tried it on my own and with a bit help from someone else I managed to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Guys I've created a solution for reverse.

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
using (write = XmlWriter.Create(path2))
{
     write.WriteStartDocument();
     write.WriteStartElement("Customers");
     write.WriteEndElement();
     write.WriteEndDocument();
}

xd.Load(path2);

for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{    
     XmlNode node = xdoc.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[i];
     //XComment com = new XComment("-------Reversed-------");
     XmlNode xnode = xd.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Customer", null);

     XmlNode nodeId = xd.CreateElement("Id");
     nodeId.InnerText = node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;

     XmlNode nodeName = xd.CreateElement("Name");
     nodeName.InnerText = node.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;

     XmlNode nodeAge = xd.CreateElement("Age");
     nodeAge.InnerText = node.ChildNodes[2].InnerText;

     xnode.AppendChild(nodeId);
     xnode.AppendChild(nodeName);
     xnode.AppendChild(nodeAge);

     xd.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xnode);

     xd.Save(path2);
}
```

The above code first loads the contents of the file whose elements have to be reversed. Then it creates a new file and stores the elements in that file in reverse order. 
Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: Glad you gave it a try. Usually you should try and do that *before* asking here though.

Answer (score 1):

Read them in and call [.Reverse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

Alternatively use an [.OrderByDescending()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)